# Traffic manager and data replication

Tags: replication, bidirectional, azure-traffic-manager

In case, I have my applications running in 2 different regions. If I use a traffic manager to route my packet to the nearest region, from a high availability perspective, how do I manage the manage data replication between these regions?

For example, if the application server in region A fails all my traffic will be routed to the application server in region B. Does this mean I will need bi-directional replication across both regions?

Comment: I have reworded your question a little, to make it more readable. Stack Overflow encourages all users to edit, and re-edit, any question to make it better; if you have more information to add to your question to clarify what you are asking, then feel free to [edit] further.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is Yes.
for example we have three layers web,application and database.
We can create two web and two application servers with different location and can use SQL always on.
This way we can use traffic manager to point to two different regions.

Answer (score 0):

If you need data parity between the two regions, you need to implement that since TM operates at the DNS layer and is agnostic to your data model. What it will do is direct your traffic to the best healthy endpoint in terms of latency (assuming you are using the performance routing mode).